# Lua positioning/tables?

Tags: lua, lua-table

this should be trivial to some but I don't get it :s

```
if Message == "!kanebot" then
    pos = {}
    pObj = Get_GameObj(pID)
    pos = Get_Position(pObj)
    pos2:AssignX(pos2:GetX()+ 4*math.cos(Get_Facing(Get_GameObj(pID))*(math.pi / 180)))
    pos2:AssignY(pos2:GetY()+ 4*math.cos(Get_Facing(Get_GameObj(pID))*(math.pi / 180)))
    pos2:AssignZ(pos2:GetZ()+ .3)
    reinf = Create_Object("Nod_Kane", pos)
    Attach_Script_Once(reinf, "M01_Hunt_The_Player")
    Attach_Script_Once(reinf, "M00_No_Falling_Damage_DME")
    InputConsole("%s has bought a kanebot.", Get_Player_Name_By_ID(pID))
end
```

The error given is: Attempt to index global 'pos2' (a nil value)

Any ideas?

Comment: You will find a better answer if you ask this question on the Renegade Forums, as the people who built the plugin you are using LUA with are more experienced. Plus I doubt anyone would even understand what your talking about or how this stuff works here besides people who have worked with the Renegade FDS plugin before.

Comment: Also Daniel added Set_Facing and 3 other commands that make what your doing 100x easier instead of doing the 4*math.cos stuff. (Lua plugin v5, and there is one for the Tiberian Technologies patch as well.)

Comment: They are both valid points, however there are few who still use lua and can provide me with guidance. In any case, Mud's response below worked perfectly for me. I do not mind not using Set_Facing as the facing is rather irrelevant - I am simply cleaning up deprecated code to conform with new TT patch standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the position into the variable `pos`, then are indexing `pos2`.  `pos2` is never initialized, so when you try to index it (`pos2:blah`) you get an error about trying to index `nil`.

Side note: the `pos = {}` line is completely superfluous, because you overwrite `pos` two lines later. Also, most of these variables should be made local, which is both faster and avoids polluting the global namespace.

Minor refactor knowing nothing about your code and/or the API you're using:

```
if Message == "!kanebot" then
    local gameobj = Get_GameObj(pID)
    local pos = Get_Position(gameobj)
    pos:AssignX(pos:GetX()+ 4*math.cos(Get_Facing(getobj)*(math.pi / 180)))
    pos:AssignY(pos:GetY()+ 4*math.cos(Get_Facing(getobj)*(math.pi / 180)))
    pos:AssignZ(pos:GetZ()+ .3)
    local reinf = Create_Object("Nod_Kane", pos)
    Attach_Script_Once(reinf, "M01_Hunt_The_Player")
    Attach_Script_Once(reinf, "M00_No_Falling_Damage_DME")
    InputConsole("%s has bought a kanebot.", Get_Player_Name_By_ID(pID))
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this was spot on! :)